# Unsafe pointers and Clang

Tags: c, clang

Maybe it's just me having a weird day, but I have a few questions on **Clang** warnings that need a short example.

Suppose for a while to have a piece of code like this

```c
/// \file  unsafe.c
#include  <stddef.h>

static int  goo (int * pi, size_t a)
{
    return pi[a];
}

int  main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    int     goz[4] = { 0, };
    
    return goo(goz, 0);
}
```

Then you go with Clang as follows

```shell
 # clang --version
clang version 16.0.3
Target: i686-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files (x86)\LLVM\bin

 # clang -std=c11 -Weverything unsafe.c -o unsafe.exe
unsafe.c:4:24: warning: 'pi' is an unsafe pointer used for buffer access
      [-Wunsafe-buffer-usage]
static int  goo (int * pi, size_t a)
                 ~~~~~~^~
unsafe.c:6:12: note: used in buffer access here
    return pi[a];
           ^~
unsafe.c:13:13: warning: mixing declarations and code is incompatible with
      standards before C99 [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
    int     goz[4] = { 0, };
            ^
2 warnings generated.
```

1. There's an unsafe pointer. I do agree that function `goo()` has no means, with a generic pointer, to know whether an index applied to it (an arithmetic expression) is safe.
   Note that's not because I did *not* check it for NULL - I just didn't to maintain the example short.

   I can't think of a *safe pointer*, to an **arbitrary-sized** vector in **C**, that I can pass to a function that retrieves an indexed element - maybe because I'm on a weird day

   What would be a good solution for Clang's sake?
2. *Mixing declarations and code is incompatible with standards before C99*. That's cool. Here's why I asked on command-line invocation for C11 ...

   Why has it been blatantly ignored? (My weird day, I know)

EDIT: I added the `#include <stddef.h>`, as it was missing. Now that's curious: this wasn't spotted by Clang.

Comment: I reproduced the first issue. Curiously, adding a check such as `if (a < 4) return pi[a]; else return 0;` or `a < n` where `n` is an additional passed parameter, does not resolve the warning. So there is a question of what sort of test or other code Clang expects there. For the second issue, there is no conflict between compiling using a C 2011 interpretation of the standard but warning about issues that may arise for other versions of the language. That’s a compiler designer choice about how useful the warning is. And it is not a default warning but one that is requested (by `-Weverything`).

Comment: I saw there's a newer Clang/LLVM, then I updated it to version **16.0.6**, with the same result. Well, I requested `-Weverything`, but also C11: I don't think it makes sense to show warnings about a previous standard. Just think what a mess would be compiling for the next C23 features and still have all the warnings on how C99 disagrees...

Comment: About the side effect of `size_t`: Clang **16.0.6** still shows no warning/error without `stddef.h`, while on https://godbolt.org/ with **x86-64 clang 16.0.0** it shows an error and not the unsafe pointer warning ... it reappears when I add the include

Comment: OT: `int main(void)` would have reduced some noise in the example.

Comment: `-Weverything` is purposefully noisy; it includes lots of warnings that are not expected to be useful in routine work. They are for people who are scouring for the code and hence do include warnings that may affect portability to previous versions of the standard. For routine work, use `-Wall`.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes correct, I just started typing by habit the kind of `main` I use most on console applications.

Comment: @LuC How well does `int  goo (int pi[4], size_t a)`  and  `int  goo (size_t a, int pi[a])` work for you?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The first solution works well when the size is clearly determined. The second solution is great but from a logical standpoint (typically an array you work on is the first parameter you mention). I understand the concern behind the warning, it's just hardly applicable to the existing C world: almost all standard library functions working on pointers would be marked with a warning. As I dare to say a *high percentage* of good code already around.

Comment: @LuC: Re “… almost all standard library functions…”: Compilers have methods for disabling warnings in system headers (due to a premise that system headers often have to deal with ugly implementation-specific things and can be presumed to “know what they are doing”, at least for the purposes of compiling user code).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: They do not help. You can test on Compiler Explorer. `size_t a, int pi[a]` would be a problem given the code accesses `pi[a]`; you want something like `size_t n, int pi[n], size_t a`. Even `int (*pi)[4]` does not eliminate the warning, although it changes it from “unsafe pointer” to “unsafe buffer access”.

Comment: @LuC Thanks for the feedback. "from a logical standpoint (typically an array you work on is the first parameter you mention)" --> That is a style issue, not really a logical one.  As both parameters are meant to describe an object (an array), either order is logical.  True that pointer first is common, yet size first affords analysis tools more info with `ptr[size]` parameter.  I see this newer approach more useful, even if it is non-traditional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix code to avoid warning -Wunsafe-buffer-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017567/how-to-fix-code-to-avoid-warning-wunsafe-buffer-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will consider an answer to my question the comments made by @EricPostpischil about the high level of verbosity from the `-Weverything` option, along with the [description of it](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#diagnostics-enable-everything) in the Clang manual.

Although I'm not completely satisfied with Clang's *chatter*, I find it misleading to have too many messages and the fact that *"some diagnostics contradict each other"* (as reported by the documentation itself).

I admit also that I missed how Clang developers *"generally don’t recommend using it"*, so maybe I just lightheartedly abused a feature thought to **spit out** everything, instead of **spotting** everything.

Comment: I personally love that `clang` has a `-Weverything`; I find it much easier to turn off spurious warnings like `-Wno-parentheses` than scroll through all the warnings that I might be interested in.

Comment: I think `clang` basically has `-Wmost` for cautious to pedantic production use, and `-Weverything` for special reviews of C code and clang.